# How to decode txn_hash from contract function call via Python web3.py, w3.eth.sendRawTransaction

Tags: python, raw-transaction, web3.py, hash

Hi I am running Python web3.py(Not web3.js) to run this:

```
 txn = ctrtInstance.functions.setzString(zString).buildTransaction()
 print('\ntxn: '+ str(txn))
 txn['nonce'] = 3643
 txn['chainId'] = 3
 print('\ntxn: '+ str(txn))
```

#So the txn looks this: {'value': 0, 'gas': 33504, 'gasPrice': 1000000000, 'chainId': 3, 'to': '0x5227D720d8eFDcB259c6c79C74f3Cfe04DC4D4fa', 'data': '0xb32e420700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007476f204d616e2100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'nonce': 3643}

```
 signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(txn, privateKey)
 txn_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Then txn_hash looks very strange: b"\x83\xd4\t'\x9e\xec\xb7\xc0\xf5\xdd\xf9\xb9\x0fD\xdc\x81\xfb\x8d\x0e\xf7\xb5\xbc2e~\x81R\x8c]Ek|"

What is it? 
How to decode this Transaction hash?

Why does it look different from other transaction hash I've seen online?

How can I decode it so I can enter it into EtherScan to check such transaction? Thank you

Reference: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction

Comment: Have you seen the example [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)? Seems like you might not be passing in the right value into the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hex()`.

```
txnHash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
print('txnHash: '+ str(txnHash))

txnHashHex = txnHash.hex()
print('txnHash.hex(): '+ txnHashHex)
```

Output in terminal:

```
txnHash: b'\x8f\xd8\x89\xfdt\x1f\xeb4\x88\x15\xeb\xb2-\xd8D\xf6\xdb%~\xdb\x0c\xf1\xa9n\x17R\x19\xf6#\xe6\x81\xf5'
binascii.hexlify(txnHash)= b'8fd889fd741feb348815ebb22dd844f6db257edb0cf1a96e175219f623e681f5'
txnHash.hex(): 0x8fd889fd741feb348815ebb22dd844f6db257edb0cf1a96e175219f623e681f5
```

You can then take `txnHash.hex()` to EtherScan to find this transaction status :)

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a ASCII binary presentation of the bytes.

You can convert raw bytes to hex in Python:

```
 import binascii
 print binascii.hexlify(b"\x83\xd4\t'\x9e\xec\xb7\xc0\xf5\xdd\xf9\xb9\x0fD\xdc\x81\xfb\x8d\x0e\xf7\xb5\xbc2e~\x81R\x8c]Ek|")

 83d409279eecb7c0f5ddf9b90f44dc81fb8d0ef7b5bc32657e81528c5d456b7c
```

Comment: Hey. thank you. So why Ropsten EtherScan could not find such transaction? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you open an another question with the details what is your transaction hash, how are you connected to Ropsten network and how do you look it up on Ropsten as the question you ask in the comment is a different question.

Comment: Thank you Mikko. txnHash.hex() is actually more convenient :)